# Command line "launch path not accessible"

Tags: swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, osx-elcapitan

I recently found out that I can create Swift command line scripts.

I decided to see if I could build my Xamarin project using it.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

print("Building Script")

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath

func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String] = []) -> NSString? {

    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments = arguments

    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    return output
}

if let output = shell("/Applications/Xamarin\\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool", arguments: ["-v build", "\"--configuration:Beta|iPhone\"", "MyApp.iOS.sln"]) {
    print(output)
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that you actually want to execute the shell and have it execute the mdtool, rather than directly execute mdtool

Try passing "/bin/bash" as the launchpath, and then include the path to mdtool as part of the argument string.

Comment: When I changed the code to look like this `shell("/bin/bash", arguments: ["/Applications/Xamarin\\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool", "-v build", "\"--configuration:Beta|iPhone\"", "MyApp.iOS.sln"])` I now longer get the exception.  Instead I get `/bin/bash: /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool: No such file or directory`

Comment: interesting - I wonder if escaping the space is necessary?  Or maybe you need a single \ instead of \\?  I would play with that, or try creating a symlink that doesn't have the space in it?

Comment: I have it working!  `shell("/bin/bash", arguments: ["-c", "'/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool' -v build '--configuration:Beta|iPhone' MyApp.iOS.sln"])`  You help has been invaluable.  What is the best way to share the answer on this?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I encounter a similar problem, but my solution is different.

**I fix the problem by changing the permission mode of the script. Specifically, `chmod 777 xxx`. The key is to give the execution permission.**

Let's conduct a controlled experiment to verify it:

1. prepare a script with path `/tmp/a.sh` and permission `666`

   The content of `/tmp/a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo aaa
```

2. prepare a `swift` script to launch the script:

```
import Foundation

let fileManager = FileManager.default
let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath

func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String] = []) -> NSString? {

    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    return output
}

if let output = shell(launchPath: "/tmp/a.sh", arguments: []) {
    print(output)
}
```

The output is:

```
... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'launch path not accessible'
```

3. change the permission of `/tmp/a.sh` to `777` (by granting the execution permission) and then re-run the `swift` script:

```
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

My version that is intended to highlight all sorts of expected results. You can replace `ParsingError.encodingFailure` and `OS.Error.processFailure` with your own `Error` implementations.

```
/// Getting a `Result` from a shell command
public func process(_ command: String) -> Result<String, Swift.Error> {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    process.standardError = errorPipe

    process.launch()

    let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    guard let output = String(data: outputData, encoding: .utf8) else {
        return .failure(ParsingError.encodingFailure(data: outputData))
    }

    let errorData = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    guard let errorOutput = String(data: errorData, encoding: .utf8) else {
        return .failure(ParsingError.encodingFailure(data: errorData))
    }

    process.waitUntilExit()
    let status = Int(process.terminationStatus)

    if status == 0, errorOutput.isEmpty {
        return .success(output)
    } else {
        return .failure(OS.Error.processFailure(code: status, message: errorOutput))
    }
}
```